# Best way to implement an SFTP server solution?

Tags: security, https, ssh, aes, sftp

I'm currently setting up a commercial SFTP server and I'm just looking for some of your opinions on the set-up I'm currently thinking of implementing, as well as a recommendation as to what commercial Secure FTP server software would be best to suit. Bear in mind that the data i'm responsible for is highly sensitive so any comments/feedback is much appreciated.

Here's the scenario:

1) Before file upload, files are compressed & encrypted using AES 256 with a salt.

2) Files uploaded from the clients' server over SFTP (port 22) to our SFTP server.

3) Files are then downloaded over HTTPS by our other client using one time password verification (strong 10 char alphanumeric password)

The specifics of the implementation I'm thinking of are:

For part (2) above, the connection is opened using host key matching, public key authentication and a user name/password combination. The firewall at both sides is restricted to only allow the static IP of the client server to connect.

For part (3), the other client is supplied with a user name/password on a per user basis (for auditing) to log into their jailed account on the server. the encryption password for the file itself is supplied on a per file basis, so i'm trying to apply two modes of encryption at all times here (except when the files are resting on the server).

Along with dedicated firewalls on both sides, Access control on the SFTP server will be configured to block IP addresses with a certain number of failed attempts over a short time, invalid passwords attempts will lock out users, password policies will be implemented etc.

I like to think that I've covered as much as possible but I'd love to hear what you guys think about this implementation?

For the commercial server side of things, I've narrowed it down to GloalSCAPE SFTP w/ SSH  & HTTP module or JSCAPE Secure FTP server - I'll be assessing the suitability of each over the weekend but if any of you have any experience with either i'd love to hear about it also.

Comment: Not really programming related. May I suggest some alternative places to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 7):

Since the data is clearly both important and sensitive from your clients' perspectives, I'd suggest you consult a security professional.  Home-grown solutions are typically a combination of over- and underkill, resulting in mechanisms that are both inefficient and insecure.  Consider:

- The files are pre-encrypted, so the only gain from SFTP/HTTPS is encryption of the session itself (*e.g.* login), but...
- You're using PKI for upload and OTP for download, so there's no risk of exposing passwords, only user IDs -- is that significant to you?
- How will you transmit the one-time passwords?  Is the transmission secure?
- Keep in mind that any lockout scheme should be temporary, otherwise a hacker can disable the entire system by locking each account.

Questions to ask yourself:

- What am I protecting?
- From whom am I protecting it?
- What are the attack vectors?
- What are the likelihoods and risks of a breach?

Once you've answered those questions, you'll have a better idea of the implementation.

In general:

- Your choice of AES256 + salt is very reasonable.
- Multi-factor authentication is probably better than multiple iterations of encryption.  It's often thought of as "something you have, plus something you know," such as a certificate and a password, requiring both for access.

As far as available utilities, many off-the-shelf packages are both secure and easy to use.  Look into OpenSSH, OpenVPN, and vsftp for starters.

Good luck - please let us know what method you choose!

Comment: +1 for suggestion to bring in someone who does this for a living

Comment: I guess the point of encrypting content before passing through a sftp channel is that the content remains encrypted on server, so server guys cannot peek at it. Using an sftp server is probably just for convenience (for secure authentication).

Comment: The questions you pose here are really something people should think through before diving into protocols and algorithms. +1 for that.

Comment: HTTPS also provides end-point authentication. Plain OTP is trivially MITM-able. High-value transactions require consideration of physical security, business continuity, etc.

Answer (score 2):

So what's wrong with OpenSSH that comes with Linux and the BSDs?

Answer (score 1):

```
Before file upload, files are compressed & encrypted using AES 256 with a salt.
```

This part rings some alarm bells...have you written some code to do this encryption/compression? How are you doing the key management? You also say your key is password derived, so your use of AES 256 and salt is giving you a false sense of security - your real key space is much less. Also the use of the term 'salt' is inappropriate here, which suggests further weaknesses.

You would be better off to use a well proven implementation (e.g. something like PGP or GPG).

Also, if you use PGP style public key encryption for the file itself (and decent key management), the security of your SFTP server will matter a lot less. Your files could be encrypted at rest.

The argument for the security of the rest of the system is very convoluted (lots of protocols, authentication schemes, and controls) - it would be a lot easier to secure the file robustly, then do best practices for the rest (which will matter a lot less and also be independent controls).

Comment: Does PGP or GPG give you a symmetric cipher? That seems what he needs.

Comment: They do, however I would recommend he uses the public key methods - he's already managing public keys anyway so he may as well use them where it counts.

Comment: I would argue against using public keys in this scenario. They require that you know the recipient's key at encoding time, which might not be the case here.

Comment: What I meant was GPG/PGP gives you a list of ciphers to choose from, not a specific one. In fact, AES256 is one of them. Public key is only used for upload. The download side uses OTP. So it might not be easy.

Comment: Yes, but I think all of that is independent - also it's convoluted and sounds like 'security via complexity', which is an anti-pattern. Secure the file independently first, then see what threats remain. I also +1'd the idea to get a security reviewer in.

Comment: @Guillame - no different than the current requirement to know some password in advance. Even if the public key was that of the server, it would still be an improvement for that hop.

Comment: ...though I should add, if only doing encryption to and fro the server, it seems pointless as sftp already does it.